# Is there a way to get two songs on a single page using lilypond-book?

Tags: lilypond

I am currently using Frescobaldi to edit my lilypond files. I have several short songs (a half-page or less) that I would like to combine into a set with more than one song on each page.  Currently, the only solution I've found is to use `\book part{}`, but that creates a single pdf with one song per page. Right now, in a seven-song set, everyone has to layout seven sheets of paper across the table to see everything and it would be nice if I could reduce it to three pages or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just put several scores below each other. Each of them can have an own `\header`. You cannot use `title` or `composer` here, but you can use the `piece` option to give each of these scores a title.

```
\version "2.19.83"

\header {
  title = "A couple of songs"
  tagline = ##f
}

\score {

  \header {
    piece = \markup { \vspace #'2 \fill-line { \bold \huge "The first song" } }
  }

  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
  } \relative c' {
    c4 d e f g1 \bar "|."
  }

}

\score {

  \header {
    piece = \markup { \vspace #'2 \fill-line { \bold \huge "The second song" } }
  }

  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
  } \relative c' {
    c4 d e f g1 \bar "|."
  }

}
```

---

If you need every song to have a title and a composer, it may be easier to just set `print-all-headers = ##t` in the `\paper` block (see [this link](http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/Bookpart-without-page-break-td4747.html)).

```
\version "2.19.83"

\paper {
  print-all-headers = ##t
}

\header {
  tagline = ##f
}

\score {

  \header {
    title = "The first song"
    composer = "C. Omposer"
  }

  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
  } \relative c' {
    c4 d e f g1 \bar "|."
  }

}

\score {

  \header {
    title = "The second song"
    composer = "C. Omposer"
  }

  \new Staff \with {
    instrumentName = "Soprano"
  } \relative c' {
    c4 d e f g1 \bar "|."
  }

}
```

Comment: Adding the `print-all-headers = ##t` and stacking scores was exactly what I needed. I'm using different songs, not just different sections, so I was looking to keep the details (i.e., title, composer, meter, etc.).